# I have a CSV file that has 3 column. Need help to format correctly via SQL SSIS Import

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, sql-server, import, ssis

I have an CSV file being dropped to a file location once a day.  When SSIS picks it up it's failing due to format issue since it has 3 columns and not delimited with 1 column.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Sample image below:

[image: CSV File]

Comment: Could you show an example of the bad data and what you would like it to be like.

Comment: Please check the link int he question

Comment: To what format would you like to transform this CSV?

Comment: To a normal excel output with 30 columns.  This daily file get dumped to a file location as a csv via SAP, but with a 3 column instead of the single column.  It's difficult to configure to a normal table with headers.

Comment: Could you please add an example.